# How to replace all null with empty String on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Good day,

is there a way to do a coalesce once and replace all posible null column with empty string or the one you set.

suppose to be the way its done is like

```
select coalesce(col1,'') as col1, coalesce(col2,'') as col2, coalesce(col3,'') as col3 from table1
```

is there a way to do this more easily as I have to convert most of my queries into this to replace null fields with " " empty string..

something like

```
select coalesce(*,'') from tablename where col1=1
```

it really looks wrong though. but you'll get the idea

currently Im using laravel query 
eg.

```
 $data = DB::table('table_name)->where('col1',1)->get();
```

this converts to `"select * from table_name where col1=1";`

and result is an array of object:

```
                [{
                        "id": 319,
                        "owner": 830,
                        "name": "new items22",
                        "date_added": "2017-10-05 22:12:59",
                        "last_modified": null,
                        "schedule": 54,
                        "day_index": 0,
                        "day": "Sunday",
                        "type": null,
                        "open": null,
                        "close": null,
                        "special": "closed"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 320,
                        "owner": 830,
                        "name": "another ITEM",
                        "date_added": "2017-10-05 22:12:59",
                        "last_modified": null,
                        "schedule": 54,
                        "day_index": 1,
                        "day": "Monday",
                        "type": null,
                        "open": "09:00:00",
                        "close": "17:00:00",
                        "special": "open"
                    }]
```

but what I want to achieve is instead of having a null value, replace it with "" or emptry string.

Comment: You also seem to have integers and dates, you can't replace those with an empty string.

Comment: You should try to work this out in the client logic. A `NULL` represents a not-given value in the database, an empty string represents an empty string. If you really just want the entries to be "empty", try to check within your client whether there's a NULL.

Comment: yeah right @stefan M. I agree but the client's programmer was not really capable of adjusting the code and I have no choice as a server side but to try to give him what he wants. xD

Comment: do you think theres no way to do it except by assigning default value on db?

Comment: Best I can think of is using dynamic SQL as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6739336/2768231)

Comment: I guess im doomed.. like I have a million queries to update omg xD

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you set your default value on your database or make your custom default value.
I hope this will help.

Comment: yep I think I should go with that path, but Im hesitate coz Im also was using 'if(x != null)' on many functions.. thats why im trying to just edit the result value instead of editing the db .. thanks for the thoughts though